# DataGridView isn't saving programmatic changes to cells

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a checkbox in a databound DataGridView, that when checked, opens a pop-up form.  I fill in the form and close it, and the data in the form is populated in the row. But the changes aren't being saved.

I am able to manually edit cells and these are saved successfully. But the programmatically aren't saved for some reason - which I've had no success in determining why.  Can somebody help please?

```
    private void dgvItemsTable_CellValueChanged ( object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e )
    {

      if ( dgvItemsTable.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == soldColumn &&
        (bool)dgvItemsTable.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value == true )
      {
        formSoldItemPopup.FillComboBoxAutoComplete ( dataSetItems, expenseTypeColumn, true ); 
        DialogResult dialogResult = formSoldItemPopup.ShowDialog ();
        if ( dialogResult == DialogResult.OK )
        {
          dgvItemsTable.BeginEdit ( true );

          dgvItemsTable.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[salesChannelIDColumn].Value = Int32.Parse ( salesChannelID );
          dgvItemsTable.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[salePriceColumn].Value = formSoldItemPopup.SalePrice;
          dgvItemsTable.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[saleDateColumn].Value = formSoldItemPopup.SaleDate;
          dgvItemsTable.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[expensesColumn].Value = formSoldItemPopup.Expenses;
          dgvItemsTable.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[expenseTypeColumn].Value = formSoldItemPopup.ExpenseType;
          dgvItemsTable.Rows[e.RowIndex].SetValues ();

          dgvItemsTable.EndEdit ();

          UpdateItemsDatabase ();      
        }
      }
    }


    private void dgvItemsTable_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged ( object sender, EventArgs e )
    {
      if ( dgvItemsTable.IsCurrentCellDirty )
      {
        dgvItemsTable.CommitEdit ( DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.CurrentCellChange );
      }
    }


    private void dgvItemsTable_CellEndEdit ( object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e )
    {
      UpdateItemsDatabase ();
    }
```

I have also tried getting the databound DataRow and updating that, but the changes are still not persistent.

```
DataRow dataRow = ( (DataRowView)dgvItemsTable.SelectedRows[0].DataBoundItem ).Row;
dataRow.BeginEdit ();
dataRow[salesChannelIDColumn] = Int32.Parse ( salesChannelID );
dataRow[salePriceColumn] = formSoldItemPopup.SalePrice;
dataRow[saleDateColumn] = formSoldItemPopup.SaleDate;
dataRow[expensesColumn] = formSoldItemPopup.Expenses;
dataRow[expenseTypeColumn] = formSoldItemPopup.ExpenseType;
dataRow.EndEdit ();
dataRow.AcceptChanges ();
```

**UPDATE**

So, I had some success with the below code - but ONLY if I don't include the two lines for the pop-up form. Which kind of defeats the purpose - I need the details from the form to populate row. :-(

Does anyone have any ideas why the form prevents the row from being successfully updated?

```
    private void button1_Click ( object sender, EventArgs e )
    {
      currentColumnBeingEdited = dgvItemsTable.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
      currentRowBeingEdited = dgvItemsTable.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
      string salesChannelID =
        dgvSelectedSalesChannel.Rows[dgvSelectedSalesChannel.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[salesChannelIDColumn].Value.ToString ();

      formSoldItemPopup.FillComboBoxAutoComplete ( dataSetItems, expenseTypeColumn, true );
      formSoldItemPopup.ShowDialog ();

      dgvItemsTable.CurrentCell = dgvItemsTable.Rows[currentRowBeingEdited].Cells[soldColumn];
      dgvItemsTable.Rows[currentRowBeingEdited].Cells[soldColumn].Value = true;
      dgvItemsTable.BeginEdit ( false );
      dgvItemsTable.EndEdit ();
      dgvItemsTable.NotifyCurrentCellDirty ( true );

      dgvItemsTable.CurrentCell = dgvItemsTable.Rows[currentRowBeingEdited].Cells[salesChannelIDColumn];
      dgvItemsTable.Rows[currentRowBeingEdited].Cells[salesChannelIDColumn].Value = salesChannelID;
      dgvItemsTable.BeginEdit ( false );
      dgvItemsTable.EndEdit ();
      dgvItemsTable.NotifyCurrentCellDirty ( true );

      dgvItemsTable.CurrentCell = dgvItemsTable.Rows[currentRowBeingEdited].Cells[saleDateColumn];
      dgvItemsTable.Rows[currentRowBeingEdited].Cells[saleDateColumn].Value = formSoldItemPopup.SaleDate;
      dgvItemsTable.BeginEdit ( false );
      dgvItemsTable.EndEdit ();
      dgvItemsTable.NotifyCurrentCellDirty ( true );

      dgvItemsTable.CurrentCell = dgvItemsTable.Rows[currentRowBeingEdited].Cells[salePriceColumn];
      dgvItemsTable.Rows[currentRowBeingEdited].Cells[salePriceColumn].Value = formSoldItemPopup.SalePrice;
      dgvItemsTable.BeginEdit ( false );
      dgvItemsTable.EndEdit ();
      dgvItemsTable.NotifyCurrentCellDirty ( true );

      dgvItemsTable.CurrentCell = dgvItemsTable.Rows[currentRowBeingEdited].Cells[expensesColumn];
      dgvItemsTable.Rows[currentRowBeingEdited].Cells[expensesColumn].Value = formSoldItemPopup.Expenses;
      dgvItemsTable.BeginEdit ( false );
      dgvItemsTable.EndEdit ();
      dgvItemsTable.NotifyCurrentCellDirty ( true );

      dgvItemsTable.CurrentCell = dgvItemsTable.Rows[currentRowBeingEdited].Cells[expenseTypeColumn];
      dgvItemsTable.Rows[currentRowBeingEdited].Cells[expenseTypeColumn].Value = formSoldItemPopup.ExpenseType;
      dgvItemsTable.BeginEdit ( false );
      dgvItemsTable.EndEdit ();
      dgvItemsTable.NotifyCurrentCellDirty ( true );


      dgvItemsTable.CurrentCell = dgvItemsTable.Rows[currentRowBeingEdited + 1].Cells[itemIDColumn];

      dgvItemsTable.CommitEdit ( DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.CurrentCellChange );
      dgvItemsTable.EndEdit ();

      UpdateItemsDatabase ();

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I finally found out what was going one. By tracking the changes to the DataTable, I found that accepting the changes at the DataRow level cleared the changes at the DataTable level. Below is the final code that works perfectly.

```
     DataTable dataTableSold = dataSetItems.Tables["Table"];
     DataRow[] dataRowSold = dataTableSold.Select ( "[" + itemIDColumn + "] = '" + itemID + "'" );

     dgvItemsTable.BeginEdit ( false );
     dataRowSold[0].BeginEdit ();
     dataRowSold[0][salesChannelIDColumn] = salesChannelID;
     dataRowSold[0][salePriceColumn] = formSoldItemPopup.SalePrice;
     dataRowSold[0][saleDateColumn] = formSoldItemPopup.SaleDate;
     dataRowSold[0][expensesColumn] = formSoldItemPopup.Expenses;
     dataRowSold[0][expenseTypeColumn] = formSoldItemPopup.ExpenseType;
     dataRowSold[0].EndEdit ();

     dgvItemsTable.Update ();
     UpdateItemsDatabase ();
```